# Neo4j and Cypher syntax: match all the paths among a group/collection of nodes

Tags: collections, neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to match all the paths (up to a certain length) among a group of nodes. I can successfully do so by issuing the following query:

```
MATCH (n) WHERE ID(n) IN [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
MATCH (m) WHERE ID(m) IN [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
MATCH paths = allShortestPaths((n)-[*..3]-(m))
RETURN paths
```

I'm satisfied with both the result itself and its speed. What I don't understand is whether there is a way of defining a variable to define the collection [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] just once. Sort of:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
MATCH (n) WHERE ID(n) IN x
MATCH (m) WHERE ID(m) IN x
MATCH paths = allShortestPaths((n)-[*..3]-(m))
RETURN paths
```

Is this possible? I've tried several alternatives (using WITH and AS) but with no luck.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
WITH [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] AS x
```

As in:

```
WITH [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] AS x
MATCH (n) WHERE ID(n) IN x
MATCH (m) WHERE ID(m) IN x
MATCH paths = allShortestPaths((n)-[*..3]-(m))
RETURN paths
```

By the way, there seems to be a regression in neo4j-community-2.2.0-M03, which causes an error with the above query. M02 seems to have no problems.

Comment: Yes, it's what I did. What I get in this case is:
Failed to create a plan for the given QueryGraph QueryGraph(Set(),Set(IdName(n), IdName(m)),Set(IdName(x)),Selections(Set(Predicate(Set(IdName(m), IdName(x)),In(FunctionInvocation(FunctionName(ID),false,Vector(Identifier(m))),Identifier(x))), Predicate(Set(IdName(n), IdName(x)),In(FunctionInvocation(FunctionName(ID),false,Vector(Identifier(n))),Identifier(x))))),List(),Set(),Set(ShortestPathPattern(Some(IdName(paths)),PatternRelationship(IdName(  UNNAMED115),(IdName(n),IdName(m)),BOTH,List(),VarPatternLength(1,Some(3))),false)))

Comment: Neo.DatabaseError.Statement.ExecutionFailure

Comment: What version of neo4j are you using?

Comment: neo4j-community-2.2.0-M03. I need 2.2 because of the fast csv importer.

Comment: Try neo4j-community-2.2.0-M02. This looks like a regression in M03, which you [should report](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues).

Comment: Thanks @cybersam, you're right. Indeed it's a regression as the same query works as expected in version 2.2.0-M02. I reported the regression at https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/3994 . Cheers